# How to create a dymanic function in ASP.NET MVC with Web API and EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-web-api

Sorry all , my English isn't very well , so I will try to use code to tell everyone what I need.In format situations,I will create 2 controller when I have 2 models**(ex: users/product)** , as following

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var users= new users() { id = 1};
var jsonText = serializer.Serialize(users);
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:65370/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

**///////////////**

```
var a = client.PostAsync("api/users", users, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result; (client)  
var b = client.PostAsync("api/product", product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result; (client)
```

and then when the users and product controllers was created the post code should be like as following

> public IHttpActionResult Postusers(users aa) {} (server)
>       public IHttpActionResult Postproduct(product bb) {} (server)

I just want to create 1 controller for above  like as follwing

```
var b = client.PostAsync<users/product>("api/all", product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).Result;(client)

public IHttpActionResult Post<T>(Object ForAll) where T : new() {} (server)
```

how can i building this structure,please help me to do this serious question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a generic base controller like this:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ApiController
    where T : class
{
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Post(T obj)
    {
        // ......
    }

    // some other common methods
}
```

and then you inherit from that controller for each of your entities:

```
public class UsersController : BaseController<User>
{}

public class ProductsController : BaseController<Product>
{}
```

this way you can keep your conventions, so `"api/users"` and `"api/products"` routes will work and the common code is refactored to a generic method.

Comment: Hi William ,thankyou so much for your help , this is a great way ,however , for your code on Controller , it is one controller in the ***.cs , or 2 controllers,PS I hope it is just needed 1 Controller to deal with all of controllers ,this is a possible or not ?? thanks again

Comment: Sorry William , I mean can i setup one ***Controller for all , if I have 100 controllers , i have to write 100 functions in the the *.cs . thanks

Comment: If you want only one controller you can use some convention for the routing and use reflection to activate the controllers but it will be more complicated.

Comment: thanks again, do you have any references or information to give me for research,i hope i can do it ,if you do mind .

Comment: you can have a controller that takes the name of the resource as a string so when you call `/api/users` it receives `users` as a string, then (using reflection) obtain the type `User` and then activate the generic controller (using reflection again) with `User`

Comment: Hi William , it is a great idea , I will try to do it and then hopefully you can help me to modify more than useful , thank again .